# How to add 58/Text into the server's Logon reply using QuickFIX

Tags: quickfix

I want to start a QuickFIX server from a specified sequence (let's say 100)
The way real exchanges do this is by adding tag 58="sequence expected 100"

1. How Can I add tag 58 to the logon replay?
2. How can I set the next expected sequence number in the server to be 100?

I have my own client - so only the server side interests me

Comment: Which "real exchanges" do this? Actually this is done by using ResendRequest processing. Please elaborate.

Comment: BarkleysSubM, for example, sends 58=expecting: 100 on its logon reply

Comment: in any case - this is what I need from the server - is it possible to do?